# how to exclude specific link or logged in users from being cached in memcache?

Tags: caching

I am using memcache 1.1.2.3.  when the editors try to create new article they face a problem with uploading images. image upload got broken in the middle of the uploading process. IMCE and imagemanager do not have any problem. i think te problem is with memcache.
how can i exclude logged-in users from being cached in memcache, or how can i tell memcache to exclude some pages (like the link that create new article')?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to disable memcache first ? Because memcache caches queries so I don't think you can exclude a page from it.

Comment: I have about 100K page view/day and MOST of them are anonymous users. i dont want to affect the speed of the website by disabling the memcache module

Comment: I understand but I wasn't recommended you to do this on your production server. It is a suggestion to be really sure the problem come from memcache.

Comment: Thanks Tostinni.. do you know, sometimes when you fail in a problem your brain stops working :D...
i tried disabling all caching levels on my staging server, and problem persists!! i can't imagine what might cause this!! :((

Comment: I sure do ;) but here I think it's quite tough to pinpoint, I'm not sure I can be of great help to you. Good luck and get some rest it helps approaching it with a clear mind.